# elisp: What does "setf" do?

Tags: variables

I read the official documentation.
Here's what not clear:

- Scope: If I do a `setf` in a function, is that visible in another function.
- Undo: How do I undo it.

in ruby, you can do

```
def myfunc
  a = "foo"
end
```

so is `(setf a "foo")` equivalent to `a = "foo"` ?

Comment: Whether it's visible in another function is *entirely* a question of the scope of the variable in question.  See `C-h i g (eintr)Prevent confusion` and `(elisp)Variable Scoping`.

Comment: @phils I'm not sure about that - see the example at the end of my answer. I can't really explain it very clearly.

Comment: @Tyler See my comment about the pointer structure of conses below your answer. The effect has nothing to do with scope. So phils is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `setf` indicates it is a generalized version of `setq`, and `setq` has global scope. In elisp you usually use `(let ...)` when you want a local variable. You can see this for yourself:

```el
(setf a "foo")
(message a) ;; => foo

(defun my-fun ()
  (setf a "bar"))

(my-fun)
(message a) ;; => bar
```

You can't undo this, unless you manually save the previous value somewhere so you can later restore it.

No knowing how scoping works in Ruby, I can't answer your third question.

As @tobias points out, my example was overly-simplistic; you'd normally just use `setq` for a case like this. The value of `setf` is that it lets you assign values to PLACES. That is, not only can you assign a value to the symbol `tmp`:

```el
(setf tmp '("foo" "bar"))
```

You can also assign a value to the PLACE defined as the the `car` of `tmp`:

```el
(setf (car tmp) "whoopie")
(print tmp) ;; ("whoopie" "bar")
```

There are quite a number of functions you can use as PLACES for `setf`. See the manual page `(info "(elisp) Setting Generalized Variables")` for the details.

As @phils and @tobias point out in comments, `setf` doesn't change Emacs' normal
scoping behaviour. However, for the novice (like me in this case), it does
some things that might suprise you.

When you set the value of a symbol, you're really defining a pointer. The
symbol points to a memory address, and when you evaluate it Emacs gives you
that value. When you set the value of a PLACE, you're actually modifying
the data stored at that address, not the pointer. Which means everything
that points to that address appears to have its value changed.

Here's a couple of examples that helped me sort this out. First, we can use
`setf` to set the value of a symbol, which is exactly what `setq` does.

```el
(setq tmp1 '(1))

(let ((loc1 tmp1)) ;; loc1 points to the same address as tmp1

  ;; setf updates symbol loc1 to point at a new address,
  ;; which contains the value '(2)
  (setf loc1 '(2))

  (print loc1)) ;; => '(2)

(print tmp1) ;; => '(1), nothing changed, tmp1 still points to the same 
             ;; address, and that address has its original value
```

Here, we set up a local variable with `let`, and none of the changes to
that variable show up in the global context.

Now we use `setf` to change the PLACE `(car loc1)` instead of the symbol
`loc1`:

```el
(let ((loc1 tmp1)) ;; loc1 points to the same address as tmp1

  ;; setf updates PLACE (car loc1) to change the value at the address it
  ;; points to
  (setf (car loc1) 2)

  (print loc1)) ;; => '(2)


(print tmp1) ;; => '(2), tmp1 still points to the same address, but the 
             ;; value at that address changed!
```

This is the tricky bit. We modified the local variable `loc1`, and that
change appears to have leaked out of the scope of the `let` to change our
global variable `tmp1`. But it didn't really. `tmp1`, which is really a
pointer, is the same as it always was, a pointer to an address. `setf`
allowed us to change the value stored at that addresss, without changing
the symbol itself.

Comment: According to the page https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope the special Ruby case with a letter as leading character of the identifier defines a local binding. That is roughly that what you get if you enclose the `(setf a "bar")` in `my-fun` into `(let (bar) ...)`.

Comment: Currently the example targets exactly the application case of the OP **but** it is not the real application case for `setf`. I know that you know that it does just not make sense to use `setf` for that case. `setq` is absolutely sufficient for that case. You could make the answer nicer if you add a real application case such as `(setf (car a) "foo")`. The question of the scope of the setting also becomes more interesting for that case, e.g., `(setq l '("foo")) (let ((a l)) (setf (car a) "bar")) (message (car l))` is a nice one.

Comment: @Tobias ok, I tried a more extended answer. It gets confusing after the first bit!

Comment: See [CAR and CDR on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR). car and cdr are **pointers** to data. When you `(setq b l)` both pointers are copied from `l` to `b` (**not** the data!). On the other hand `(car b)` refers to the **data** stored at the place where the first pointer points to. That is the same target for `l` and `b`. ==> `(car l)` and `(car b)` refer to the same storage place after `(setq b l)`. Thus `(setf (car b) ...)` changes `(car b)` but that **is the same** as `(car l)`.

Comment: See also the example `(progn (setq a '(1 2 3)) (setq b a) (setcar b 10) a)` which is `let`-free and therefore is independent of the discussion about local scope. Note, that the common lisp version `(progn (setq a '(1 2 3)) (setq b a) (setf (car b) 10) (print a))` also works on the [common lisp repl](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lisp_online.php).

Comment: Wow, thanks @tobias. I'm starting to understand that now. I don't have time to update my answer, but I think I have a better example to clarify where I was confused.

Comment: @tobias see my update - am I making sense yet?